# A* (A Star) - Algorithm | How to go back when there are walls?

Tags: java, data-structures, processing, path-finding, a-star

I'm currently trying to implement the A* (A star) - Algorithm. I already got it working when I don't have walls and when it is only needed to go besides the wall. My problem now is that when I'm placing the start inside of my walls, my algorithm is calculating infinitely as I think it doesn't go backward. Can you guys please help me?

Here is the code from the node class:

```
int[][] mMap; // if there is a wall => 1

int[][] mAStarField;
ArrayList<AStarNode> mAStarPath;

public class AStarNode implements Comparable<AStarNode>{ 
  public int x; 
  public int y; 
  public float c;
  public AStarNode p; 
  public AStarNode(int x, int y, float c, AStarNode p) { 
    this.x = x; //X pos
    this.y = y; //Y pos
    this.c = c; //Cost to get to the node
    this.p = p; //Parent of the node
  }
  //override the compareTo method 
  public int compareTo(AStarNode node) 
  { 
    if (c == node.c) 
      return 0; 
    else if (c > node.c) 
      return 1; 
    else
      return -1; 
    } 
  
  
} 

public class Node { 
  public int x; 
  public int y; 
  public int z; 
  public int w; 
  public Node(int x, int y, int z, int w) { 
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z; 
    this.w = w;
  }
}
```

This is the code from my A* algorithm:

```
//Pathfinding with A*
//return path length
int updateAStar() {


  //Needed for drawing:
  //Array containing the distance to the start node (filled with max int at start)
  mAStarField = new int[mMap.length][mMap[0].length];
  //List containing the found path
  mAStarPath = new ArrayList<AStarNode>();

  for (int j = 0; j < mMap.length; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < mMap[0].length; k++) {
      mAStarField[j][k]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
  }

//AStarNode(x,y,c,w)
  //x X pos
  //y Y pos
  //c Cost to get to the node
  //p Parent of the node

  //List can be sorted expensive but simple by c value with
  //Collections.sort(openList); 
  ArrayList<AStarNode> openList = new  ArrayList<AStarNode>();
  ArrayList<AStarNode> closedList = new  ArrayList<AStarNode>();

  int dist = abs(mStartNode[0]-mEndNode[0])+abs(mStartNode[1]-mEndNode[1]);

  //If there is any target, that isn't on my field, add start node to list
  if (dist>0 && mMap[mStartNode[0]][mStartNode[1]] != 1 && mMap[mEndNode[0]][mEndNode[1]]!=1) {
    openList.add(new AStarNode(mStartNode[0], mStartNode[1], 0, null));
    mAStarField[mStartNode[0]][mStartNode[1]] = 0;
  }
  
// my code begins here (only everything from here on can be edited!)

  while(!openList.isEmpty())
  {
    Collections.sort(openList);
    AStarNode current = openList.get(0);
    
    if(current.x == mEndNode[0] && current.y == mEndNode[1])
    {
      return 1;
    }
    
    openList.remove(0);
    closedList.add(current);
    
    ArrayList<AStarNode> neighbors = new  ArrayList<AStarNode>();
    neighbors.add(new AStarNode(current.x - 1, current.y, current.c + 1, current));
    neighbors.add(new AStarNode(current.x + 1, current.y, current.c + 1, current));
    neighbors.add(new AStarNode(current.x, current.y - 1, current.c + 1, current));
    neighbors.add(new AStarNode(current.x, current.y + 1, current.c + 1, current));
    
    for(AStarNode n : neighbors)
    {
      if(n.x >= 0 && n.y >= 0 && n.x < mMap.length && n.y < mMap.length && mMap[n.x][n.y] != 1){
      
      float cost = estimateDistanceEnd(n.x, n.y);
      n.c = cost;
      
      if(closedList.contains(n) && cost >= n.c) continue;
      
      if(!openList.contains(n) || cost < n.c)
      {
        n.p = current;
        
        if(!openList.contains(n)){
          mAStarField[n.x][n.y] = (int) n.c;
          openList.add(n);
          Collections.sort(openList);
        }
      }
      }
    }
    
  }
  return -1;
}

int estimateDistanceEnd(int x, int y){
   return abs(x-mEndNode[0])+abs(y-mEndNode[1]); 
}

int estimateDistanceStart(AStarNode a){
   return abs(a.x-mStartNode[0])+abs(a.y-mStartNode[1]); 
}

int estimateDistance(AStarNode a, AStarNode b){
   return abs(a.x-b.x)+abs(a.y-b.y); 
}
```

[A picture of my current path solving result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJTYH.png)

Important: I'm only allowed to change code inside of the area I marked.

Thank you!

Comment: `it doesn't go backward` I think in the classic algorithm it pops values (previous positions) off a stack in order to reverse to a previous state.  If you're implementing your code differently you'll need to do something that is equivalent.

Comment: Using arrays of integer to store node locations... I don't approve of this (I realize that this isn't on you, don't worry).

Comment: Please do this test for me: write this one-liner (`if(closedList.contains(n) && cost >= n.c) continue;`) as a normal if and put a breakpoint _inside the if_. If I'm right, you'll never hit that breakpoint. Let me know about the result of the test by tagging me in your reply.

Comment: @laancelot I tried it and you are right. It'll never hit the breakpoint. But I can't figure out why. Edit: I think it is because I'm always creating a new node and therefore the list never contains the new one. But how should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't run the code, but I have a little idea about the the source of the issue. See, the A* algorithm doesn't "walk back" while looking for the best path. It solves the pathfinding issue by calculating the less costly way to get to the end for literally every node that it evaluates. It starts by calculating the itineraries which are the most straightforward, then if it didn't work it'll enlarge it's options until it either, uh, finds a way - or run out of options.

The principle of the closed list to avoid evaluating a node twice. As you guessed, the problem here is that you are creating new nodes for neighbors at every iteration of the pathfinding algorithm, thus making it harder for the closed list to be used correctly.

A complex object like a custom class can be compared through 3 means: it either is the same object (it refer to the same pointer (it's the same *instance*, it's at the same place in the computer's memory)), or the values are all the same whatever it's pointer is pointing, or you can define a rule to compare them. These methods would be: comparing by reference, comparing by value and operator overloading - although that last one isn't possible in java, but you can write a method to do the same.

When doing `closedList.contains(n)`, you are comparing by reference (which is the default for this kind of operation). Since all the nodes have been created on the fly, even if their coordinates are the same they all have different address in memory, and this is why this condition will never be met.

Assuming that you cannot mess with your tutor's code, you can still fix this. You almost got it right the first time! There are many ways to to fix this, in fact, and as I miss some of the context I'll be rather plain in my suggested approach: you'll write a method to fetch a specific node from a list (like the operator overloading I spoke about, but with the bare minimum effort) and we'll work by reference from this point onward.

First, create a master list of all your `AStarNode` (if you don't already have one, if you do then use that one instead):

```
// my code begins here (only everything from here on can be edited!)
ArrayList<AStarNode> nodesList = new  ArrayList<AStarNode>();
for (int j = 0; j < mapWidth; j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < mapHeight; k++) {
    nodesList.add(new AStarNode(j, k)); // I gimmicked the constructor for my own confort, you'll have to tweak this line so it fits in your code
  }
}
```

Then, write yourself a method which will return a node from an array based on given xy coordinates:

```
AStarNode GetAStarNodeByPosition(int x, int y, ArrayList<AStarNode> list) {
  for (AStarNode m : list) {
    if (m.x == x && m.y == y) {
      return m;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Now, you can use these to compare all your nodes by reference. So, now instead of instantiating new nodes all the time, you'll always fetch them from the master list, by reference:

```
ArrayList<AStarNode> neighbors = new  ArrayList<AStarNode>();
neighbors.add(GetAStarNodeByPosition(current.x - 1, current.y, nodesList));
neighbors.add(GetAStarNodeByPosition(current.x + 1, current.y, nodesList));
neighbors.add(GetAStarNodeByPosition(current.x, current.y - 1, nodesList));
neighbors.add(GetAStarNodeByPosition(current.x, current.y + 1, nodesList));
```

Also, don't forget to fix this line:

```
//openList.add(new AStarNode(mStartNode[0], mStartNode[1], 0, null));
openList.add(GetAStarNodeByPosition(mStartNode[0], mStartNode[1], nodesList));
```

Lastly, always remember to test for `null` if you know that you *may* have some in your arrays. In this case, the `GetAStarNodeByPosition` method can return a `null` if you're too close to the boundaries of the maze. You can either modify the way you add to the neighbors list so there will be no `null` in there, or you can check for null on this line:

```
if(n != null && n.x >= 0 && n.y >= 0 && n.x < mMap.length && n.y < mMap.length && mMap[n.x][n.y] != 1){
```

Honestly I would prevent the inclusion of null in the array at all, that's much safer if you modify the code further later.

Now all your nodes will relate and you'll be able to overcome obstacles which needs your algorithm to search in a more clever way than a straight line.

Have fun!